# How does an iOS screensaver app work?

Tags: ios, xcode

A client of mine recently came up with a few apps he came across while browsing online.  Specifically, he discovered that there are apps that call themselves 'screensavers', and now he wants me to make him a screensaver app.

The obvious problem is that I don't know of any way to make my app open (displacing whatever is in the background) based on a lack of user input in another app!  In fact, I would have sworn that it was completely impossible to do so.

So, to wrap up the question -- is it possible to make such an app, and if so how?  Or are those apps really, really, badly labeled?

Comment: If you've never been... they do this in the Apple Store to play little promotional videos on-screen.

Comment: I've seen 'demo' apps before, my question is can they turn themselves on based on a lack of user input (or some other approach), and if so how?

Comment: Probably an internal-use script of some sort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested 3 of the top "screen-saver" applications on my iPad. None of these can turn themselves on, without the user launching them. They are really **badly labeled** products. In a non-jailbroken device, launching the screensaver application without user interaction is **not** possible.

[Cydia Screensaver Application](http://www.iphoneroots.com/2011/04/screensaver-cydia-tweak-has-released.html) for **Jailbroken** devices.

Comment: I know I'm going to hate asking this, but 'non-jailbroken'; if they're willing to jailbreak...?

Comment: Yeah, if they are willing to jailbreak their iOS devices, you can pretty much replace the lock-screen with your screen-saver if you please.

Comment: @RonLugge See http://www.iphoneroots.com/2011/04/screensaver-cydia-tweak-has-released.html

Answer (score 2):

You're correct -- it isn't possible to open an app with no user interaction with a stock device, although there *are* jailbroken packages that will complete a task similar to this.

You should explain to your client that these "screensaver" apps usually gimmick the reader into downloading them as if they function as do screen savers on personal computers.